# SQL into Table Multiple queries same column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a web based report to show the response of certain advertisements.

```
$sql1 = "
SELECT date
     , source
     , source_desc
     , COUNT(ordernumber) count
     , SUM(ordervalue) value
     , type 
  FROM dailystats 
 WHERE client = '$client2' 
   AND event <> 'B02' 
   AND date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' 
 GROUP 
    BY source 
 ORDER 
    BY source;
    ";
```

This works fine for my table to show total values, but I want to break it down further. I currently have SOURCE {source}, DESCRIPTION {source_desc}, TOTAL ORDERS {count}, TOTAL ORDER VALUE {value}, as my headers which are populated by the above fields.

I want, as well as the current totals, to include further columns when the field "TYPE" is "P", "T" and "E". I want this to leave me with data to fill new headers (when I put them into the table) consisting of SOURCE, DESCRIPTION, WEB ORDERS, WEB ORDER VALUE, PHONE ORDERS, PHONE ORDER VALUE, POST ORDERS, POST ORDER VALUE, TOTAL ORDERS, TOTAL ORDER VALUE.

I need to create the data for the new headers, so WEB ORDERS will give me the total orders with the TYPE "E". On its own this would be something like `COUNT(ordernumber) count where type = "E"`, but I need multiple of these and I cannot get it to work.

It currently looks like this :

```
|Source|Source Description|Total Orders|Total Order Value|
|DM1   |Daily Mail 1      |500         |5,000            |
```

I want to retain this information, but add in as described above, to look like this.

```
|Source|Source Description|Web Orders|Web Order Value|Post Orders|Post Order Value|Mail Orders|Mail Order Value|Total Orders|Total Order Value|
|DM1   |Daily Mail 1      |100       |1,000          |300        |3,000           |100        |1,000           |500         |5,000            |
```

I hope I have explained my problem adequately.

Comment: You have to include those extra columns all the time, and get their values as NULL in the rows you don't care about the result. For different values based on the column `type` check `CASE type WHEN ... THEN... END` structure.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved. (One of these two products sometimes handle group by a bit different.)

Comment: MYSQL, ammended tags.

Comment: Recommend posting sample desired output.  And be leary of mysql's use of the extended group by... you may not get the desired results if you're not grouping by everything in your select.

Comment: Added desired output

Answer (score 0):

use **group_concat(type)** **as type** in your code.
(if it is wrong sry. *pls explain it clear*)

Comment: I have added further clarification to my question

Comment: where is ** type**  in the table. You need to rewrite your Question .your question not clear. IF(your column name,'true','false')

Answer (score 0):

> I want this to leave me with headers (when I put them into the table) of SOURCE, DESCRIPTION, WEB ORDERS, WEB ORDER VALUE, PHONE ORDERS, PHONE ORDER VALUE, POST ORDERS, POST ORDER VALUE, TOTAL ORDERS, TOTAL ORDER VALUE.

If i understand correctly you want to add headers to your result ? this should be done by:

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name AS **alias_name;**

Comment: I have added further clarification to my question

Comment: $sql1 = "
SELECT date
     , source
     , source_desc
     , COUNT(ordernumber) count
     , SUM(ordervalue) value
     , type 
     , extra column
     , extra column
     , SUM (colum+colum+colum etc etc)
  FROM dailystats 
 WHERE client = '$client2' 
   AND event <> 'B02' 
   AND date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' 
 GROUP 
    BY source 
 ORDER 
    BY source;
    ";

Comment: The "extra" columns need to be "COUNT(ordernumber) count where type = "P"", "SUM(ordervalue) value where type = "P"" etc etc, which I do not know how to format